# bad variable name in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y git
RUN export EOSIO_LOCATION=~/eosio/eos \
    export EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION=$EOSIO_LOCATION/../install \
    mkdir -p $EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION
RUN git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos.git $EOSIO_LOCATION \
    cd $EOSIO_LOCATION && git submodule update --init --recursive
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

And error is: `/bin/sh: 1: export: -p: bad variable name`

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently don't have any separation between the `export` and `mkdir` commands in the `RUN` statement.

You probably want to concatenate the commands with `&&`. This ensures that the previous commands (only) runs if the prior command succeds. You may also use `;` to separate commands, i.e.

```
RUN export EOSIO_LOCATION=~/eosio/eos && \
    export EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION=$EOSIO_LOCATION/../install && \
    mkdir -p $EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION
```

**NOTE** You probably don't need to `export` these variables and could:

`EOSIO_LOCATION=... && EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION=... && mkdir ...`

There's a Dockerfile `ENV` command that may be preferable:

```
ENV EOSIO_LOCATION=${PWD}/eosio/eos
ENV EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION=${EOSIO_LOCATION}/../install && \
RUN mkdir -p ${EOSIO_INSTALL_LOCATION}
```

Personal preference is to wrap env vars in `${...}` and to use `${PWD}` instead of `~` as it feels more explicit.

Comment: I'd note specifically here that `RUN export ...` has no effect beyond its immediate `RUN` statement; where the following line references `$EOSIO_LOCATION` it will expand to an empty string.  `ENV` sets a variable persistently.  I wouldn't bother using an environment variable for a filesystem path in a container, though, just set `WORKDIR /eosio` and then use relative paths from there.